# Automatic error handling with OpenAPI spec in Google Cloud Endpoints

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

In the [Google Cloud Endpoints: serving your API to the world](https://youtu.be/bR9hEyZ9774?t=34m39s) talk at Google Cloud Next '17 conference, it was presented that some request errors such as calling not existent path or providing a malformed JSON object in the body, could be handled by the ESP container and never get to the actual application code. So you get for example a nicely formatted NotFound error JSON objects as this one:

```json
{
  "code": 5,
  "message": "Method does not exist.",
  "details": [
    {
      "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.DebugInfo",
      "stackEntries": [],
      "detail": "service_control"
    }
  ]
}
```

But I don't seem to get this functionality with my app in App Engine Standard environment. What I get when I call a non existent path is "Not Found" plain text in response. I was trying to specify the `x-google-allow: configured` in my OpenAPI spec (which should be a default behavior as I understood) but that didn't work either.

Should it work in AE standard and if so, how should I modify my OpenAPI spec to make it work?

Comment: Are you using the Endpoints Frameworks? Which language are you writing your app in?

Comment: Yes, using Endpoints Frameworks in Python. So I use `endpointscfg.py` script to generate OpenAPI spec document. Should I edit the spec manually to add errors handling functionality?